# Resource not being bundled into app

Tags: macos, cocoa, resources, bundle, shader

I have shaders named basic_shader.vsh and basic_shader.fsh. I added both of these two files to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. But they are not being copied into the bundle app. And they don't appear in the Log Navigator. Xcode builder effectively ignores them.

They are located into a directory outside the source directory. I don't know if that is relevant. The funny thing is that a png image also located outside the source directory is being copied inside the bundle. My app is a Mac OS X app using Cocoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by adding into the **Copy Files** build phase (setting the destination to Resources) instead of the **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase... I don't know why it solves the problem as I don't really understand the problem, actually...

Thanks anyway...

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me as well for an "Empty Application" xcode project. There was no phase for "Copy Bundle Resources" available until I added it manually. But then it failed to do anything. I have no idea why Copy Bundle Resources isn't working on this project. But +1 for finding the alternative that works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your shaders are copied into your resources

[image]

Comment: Like I said, my shader is in the Copy Bundle Resources Build Phase... I don't understand why it doesn't get bundled into the app...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason .metal files are not regarded as resources. If you just change the extension to anything else they're copied in the bundle.